# Product import, additional images and additional image labels

Tags: magento2, product, import, csv

When we try to import products from the Magento 2 back office with the csv example below, we define several images (base, thumbnail and small) and we also add additional images.

If we define labels for base, thumbnail and small it works perfectly. However, for the labels of the additional images, it will put the text on the same image instead of on the defined images.

I've tried using the csv export of the product in question as an example, but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas? Because it would be rather annoying to have to go back over all our products to change the alternative texts on the images.

[image: example of alt text images with fail]

```
sku,base_image,base_image_label,small_image,small_image_label,thumbnail_image,thumbnail_image_label,additional_images,additional_image_labels
OUR_SKU,https://our-super-site/img5.jpg,"test base img",https://our-super-site/img4.jpg,"test small image",https://our-super-site/img3.jpg,"test thumbnail image","https://our-super-site/img1.jpg,https://our-super-site/img2.jpg","test1,test2"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, we must uncheck "field enclosure" before "check data" and import and it's work perfectly